# XSLT output Google charts

Tags: xml, xslt, charts, google-visualization

I have learned how to output images, links, and text with XSLT.

However, when I try to output Google charts, I get errors.

I searched for an answer for a few hours. I want to output this chart, for example:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=450x200&chd=t:2,4,3,1&chl=Phones|Computers|Services|Other&chtt=Company%20Sales&chco=ff0000

[image]

(I can't even output it as a link.)  Also, how can I use XML data to create a chart?

Comment: What XML data are referring to? Can you post a small example of your XML input and what you're expecting for an output?

Comment: dose it matter? i just want to output an html image with google chart link (or a google chart link).

i found the problem it goes mad when i use the character "&",how shold i output links with a lot of vars(like google charts).

resorce this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67859/xslt-cannot-get-xslt-to-output-an-even-after-escaping-the-character

not very useful because im kinda new to xslt.

Comment: There are certain characters that need to be escaped in XML. The `&` is one of them. You should encode your URLs. (One way is to use percent encoding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding.) If it's something outside of a URL, use `&amp;` (which can also be used in a URL).

Comment: solved & is a reserved char use '&amp;' insted

edit:thank you daniel i just saw your post,its good to know the full explanation. i will get a small contract job because of your help.

Answer (score 2):

check out the files listed at this [address](https://github.com/hpcc-systems/ecl-samples/pull/1/files) - they might help you out with this particular dilemna. There are a few files, one for each type of chart so choose the right one for you.

Hope it works!