# Trying to add two parameters into link with XML

Tags: xml, hyperlink, parameters

I am trying to add two parameters into a web link which is "userid" and "location" with XML. Here is my code below:

```
             <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="user_id"/>
             <tr>

             <xsl:variable name="index" select="user_id" />

                <xsl:apply-templates select="username"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="type"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="location"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="price"/>

                <td><a href="moreinfo.php?userid={$index}&location=lewisham">Click here</a></td>
```

However, it only lets me use one parameter and the other causes following errors. No matter which way I try, either one of the parameters works until I add both to the link.

> Warning: DOMDocument::load(): EntityRef: expecting ';' in
>   /home/cb222/public_nginx/level5/XSL.xsl, line: 49 in
>   /home/cb222/public_nginx/level5/rest_sbt.php on line 31
>
> Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error in
>   /home/cb222/public_nginx/level5/rest_sbt.php on line 32
>
> Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): xsltParseStylesheetProcess
>   : empty stylesheet in /home/cb222/public_nginx/level5/rest_sbt.php on
>   line 32
>
> Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): No stylesheet associated to
>   this object in /home/cb222/public_nginx/level5/rest_sbt.php on line 34

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found this post would help: [Cannot get xslt to output an (&) even after escaping the character][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67859/cannot-get-xslt-to-output-an-even-after-escaping-the-character

Comment: Thanks. The answer is that XML cannot parse '&' and so I had to use '&amp;' instead.